# Nagios, сравнение загруженности серверов

Tags: linux, плагин, мониторинг

Добрый день, товарищи! Мне нужно программно сравнивать загруженность серверов в nagios и выдавать самый не загруженный сервер (его ip) в какой нибудь файлик, это реально сделать плагином или каким либо скриптом? Никак не могу понять, откуда тянуть информацию у nagios в данный момент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nagios выдает текущие состояния мониторинга в файл status.dat. Он текстовый, находится с линуксах в каталоге /var/log/nagios

Comment: Странно, у меня нет такого файла, в /var/log/nagios3 у меня лежит папка archives и файлик nagios.log

Comment: может в вашем дистрибутиве лежит в другом месте. Файлик должен быть. Версия, судя по всему, третья, как и у меня. Ищите в другом месте. В конфигурации указывается место в параметре status_file

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, осталось узнать, как тянуть с него данные!  Зашел в nagios.cfg и увидел: status_file=/var/cache/nagios3/status.dat

Comment: servicestatus, там и все состояния сервисов на хостах. Формат, что то вроде json. например  servicestatus {
 host_name=localhost
 service_description=Swap Usage
plugin_output=SWAP OK - 100% free (31999 MB out of 31999 MB) }

Comment: Спасибо, еще раз, нашел, скрипт, который может парсить этот файл в json! Ссылка: https://github.com/lizell/php-nagios-json , да, я разобрался, там все что нужно есть и загрузка ЦП и оперативки и использование жесткого диска